# htaccess rewriterule - escape backreferences B flag alternative

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a url that contains the & symbol.  I've tried with & and %26, but both get stripped out by apache.

For example, if the url is:

```
healthyliving/fruit/apples_&_pears
```

and the rewriterule is:

```
RewriteRule ^healthyliving/fruit/([^/.]+)$ food.php?subpage=healthyliving&item=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The querystring would show "apples_&*pears", but `_GET['item']` would show "apples*".

From what I've read, most solutions use the B flag to escape backreferences.  This flag was introduced in 2.2.7.  Unfortunately we are running an earlier version and we cannot updgrade right now for various reasons.

Is there a way to achieve what I need without the use of the B flag?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the $_GET, but you could try this

```
RewriteRule ^healthyliving/fruit/(.*)_&_(.*) food.php?subpage=healthyliving&item[]=$1&item[]=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Which should give you:

```
Array ( [subpage] => healthyliving [item] => Array ( [0] => apples [1] => pears ) )
```